# Correlation between BindingType and CoercionType in the JavaScript API for Office (Word)

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-2013, apps-for-office

Its easy to use bindings in Office 2013 Task Pane Apps with `Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync`.

[The Documentaton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161120%28v=office.1501401%29.aspx) is telling me that I can insert HTML into an binding. (Word only)
When I try to do this, like in the documentation, i only get the error `The specified coercion type is not compatible with this binding type.`.

So which `Binding Type`should I use?
`matrix` and `table` seems not to be the right oney, and `text` is not working!
[The seems to be no corrent one!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/DE-DE/library/fp142273%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a great Word sample from the WikiPedia Store App on GitHub you can pull down and see https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Apps how it is injecting HTML into the Word body.